# Standard arrays seem faster than gpuArray on conv net feed forward

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am implementing Convolutional networks in MATLAB, and I added a support for GPUs (I am using gpuArrays). I implemented the feed forward part. When I run it with standard array (I have the arrays already in my workspace ready), it takes 0.15 sec. However, when I run the EXACT same thing, but the arrays being gpuArrays, which are all in my workspace prior to running the feed forward script, it takes ~1.39 sec. Can someone explain what's going on here? Thanks

**UPDATE:** I tested running time and everything suggests that the main bottleneck is my convolution part, so I will paste that part of code down here:

```
            pad = (size(layers_W{layerNum}, 1)-1) / 2;

            for imageNum = 1:options.minibatchSize
                for filterNum = 1:size(layers_W{layerNum}, 4)
                    for filterD = 1:size(layers_W{layerNum}, 3)
                        c = conv2(convInput(:, :, filterD, imageNum), ... 
                            rot90(layers_W{layerNum}(:, :, filterD, filterNum), 2), 'valid');
                       layers_activations{layerNum}(pad+1:end-pad, pad+1:end-pad, filterNum, imageNum) = ...
                            layers_activations{layerNum}(pad+1:end-pad, pad+1:end-pad, filterNum, imageNum) + ...
                            c;
                    end

                    layers_activations{layerNum}(pad+1:end-pad, pad+1:end-pad, filterNum, imageNum) = ...
                            layers_activations{layerNum}(pad+1:end-pad, pad+1:end-pad, filterNum, imageNum) + ...
                            layers_b{layerNum}(filterNum);
                end
            end

            if strcmp(options.activation, 'relu') == 1
                layers_activations{layerNum} = max(0, layers_activations{layerNum});
            elseif strcmp(options.activation, 'sigmoid') == 1
                layers_activations{layerNum} = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-layers_activations{layerNum}));
            end
```

This exact piece of code is **~52 times slower on GPU than on CPU**. Any ideas?

**UPDATE2:** Tested separately the line that does 2d convolution (~10 times slower on GPU) and the line below it that adds two matrices(~100 times slower on GPU). I am completely confused why this is happening.

Comment: It takes a while for data to travel to the GPU. If you do not have enough computations to do on the GPU(it looks like you do not) then the CPU will actually be faster.

Comment: But shouldn't it all be in GPU memory? Since the other script made these vectors and everything and they sit in workspace before I run feed forward. I am absolutely sure my GPU has enough memory to hold this all in its memory (6gb, and only testing on small network).

Comment: Not everything in a GPU is faster.  Profile your code to see what is the slowest part. Also, unless you show the whole code, its hard for us to help you

Answer (score 2):

This isn't at all a surprise. The GPU is efficient at doing convolutions on large images (HD, 4K) but not particularly at images 227x227 or smaller, such as are typical in CNNs. You need to at least be running a 3-D convolution so you can apply all the filters over each input activation in one call, rather than looping over all the filters and all the images. Try replacing the inner loop with a call to `convn`.

Smart GPU implementations of convolution in this context, such as that used by the Neural Network Toolbox in MATLAB, use custom kernels and multi-threading to take advantage of spatial parallelism and parallelism in the batch dimensions of filters and inputs. Your implementation throws away all the batch parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any source where I can find about these implementations or the way I can use those smart built-in convolutions and other operations?